# The "of" in company names—avoid or embrace?

Tags: phrases, prepositions

Are you aware of any rules, statistics, or guidelines that address the "of" in company names?

For instance, which is more accepted: Institute of Research or Research Institute? Canada Bank or Bank of Canada? What guides the choice?

Thank you in advance.

Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rule.  It's six of one, half a dozen of the other.

An organization's name is whatever its owners or directors choose to call it.  That's why we have both Indiana University being called "Indiana University" instead of "University of Indiana" and University of Michigan being called 
"University of Michigan" instead of "Michigan University."  Neither way is more correct than the other.  How it ends up is just someone's personal preference, or maybe not even that but just because they had to settle on a name and randomly chose one way over the other.

Comment: I agree.  Here in Illinois, there is the University of Illinois (U of I), a state institution (i.e., founded and run by the State of Illinois), Illinois State University (ISU), also a state institution separate from the U of I,  and Illinois College (IC), a private college.  ISU was founded as a "normal school", i.e., a college to train teachers, and the town it was in was named "Normal" in its honor.  There's town in Illinois called Oblong.   A famous headline from a local newspaper reads:  "Oblong Man Marries Normal Woman".

Comment: This is a generally sound answer. On the other hand, some entities do accept both the longer, formally correct form of their name and a shorter, of-less form. For example, in the United States, we often see both "Bureau of the Census" and "Census Bureau," and "Department of Defense" and "Defense Department."

Comment: One usually sounds, and sells, better than the other. It's an aesthetic distinction.